# AJAX calls for progress visualization on blocked UI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, excel

My project is all about creating reports of thousands of items and for downloading these reports as an Excel file. At the moment the customer has to wait in front of a blocked screen until the items are read from database and filled into the Excel file and until it is ready for downloading.

The problem is when I have about 4000 items (every item has about 10 values) it takes sometimes about 7-10 minutes (depends on the number of items) to finish the whole progress. The screen is blocked via the `BlockUI.js` tool (external code).

For a better respond I want to have progress informations in this blocked screen. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I have to tell you that I'm bad with using AJAX, JQuery and JSON. I know that I can or have to work with `Response.Write()` but I really don't know how to catch these responses in AJAX.

Next problem is - the whole progress with querying the database and creating the Excel sheet is done in a separate .cs file - not in the code behind of the .aspx page.

[image]

So when there's no `Response.Write()` how do I get the information what the website is doing at the moment?

Step by step the website/server is doing this while creating a report:

1. first method to get the items from DB
2. querying a few additional information for each item from DB
3. filling the DataTable with each item
4. second method to get other items from database
5. like 2.
6. like 3.
7. third method to get the last special items from DB
8. like 2.
9. like 3.
10. creating the Excel sheet
11. filling the Excel sheet
12. ready for download (BlockUI sets the screen free)

In C# regions it looks like

[image]

That's it. What I want or need is kind of progressbar with text to show the customer what the program is doing at the moment - how do I realize this in the most normal way?